# Method not supported in LINQ Store expression

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am using LINQ to Entities for selecting data from SQL.

Here is my statement

```
 var employee = from p in _context.employee
                      select p;

 employee = employee.Where(p =>   
 Helper.RemoveSpecialCharacters(p.IdentificationNumber).
 Equals(Helper.RemoveSpecialCharacters(search.IdentificationNumber)));

 var Results = employee.ToList();
```

I am using RemoveSpecialCharacters method which I wrote to compare both sides of comparison without special characters.

Here I Get error, "RemoveSpecialCharacters" Method is not supported by Linq->Entity and is not a valid Store Expression.

I understand that it can't be translated as SQL. But how do I make such comparison using LINQ?

RemoveSpecialCharacters Method

```
 public static string RemoveSpecialCharacters(string str)
    {
        char[] arr = str.Where(c => (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))).ToArray();

        str = new string(arr);

        return str;
    }
```

If methodname be translated to LINQ store then maybe how can I put this in linq so that sql understands it.

Comment: By the way, `var employee = from p in _context.employee select p;` is translated into `var employee = (_context.employee);` (C# Language Specification Version 5.0, 7.16.2.5 Select clauses).

Comment: Ideally you shall be able to create a MethodCall Expression, for your IQueryable query to work, it is just not able to Translate methods, when compiling `Func`  from `Expression Tree`

Comment: Check out the code using `Regex.Replace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can express your `RemoveSpecialCharacters` in SQL, you could have a SQL view presenting your employees with a computed `IdentificationNumberWithoutSpecialCharacters` column, and then filter on it.

You could also reuse your C# implementation of the method by creating a .NET assembly for SQL Server.

Comment: How do represent the `RemoveSpecialCharacters` in Sql, you shall have answered this part, Sql CLR or Dynamic Sql are not good options for the performance as the data size increase. Without code, this shall have been more of comment than answer

Answer (score 0):

> The `.ToList()` finishes off your initial DB query, and gives you an
>   in-memory representation to work with and modify to your object.

```
var employee = from p in _context.employee
                      select p.ToList();
string searchIdent = Helper.RemoveSpecialCharacters(search.IdentificationNumber);

 employee = employee.Where(p => 
 Helper.RemoveSpecialCharacters(p.IdentificationNumber).
 Equals(searchIdent));

 var Results = employee;
```

Comment: This will pull the whole employee table in memory before filtering.

Comment: yep, not something i want to do.

Comment: Even if pulling the whole table were the only solution, I would replace `.ToList()` by `.AsEnumerable()` to avoid creating the list and keeping in memory the discarded objects.